The lower bound for the automorphic $L$-function $L(s,\pi)$ at the edge of the critical strip $\Re s=1$
Let $\pi$ be any automorphic Maass form on $\text{GL}_m$ of level $N$, say. Assume that the associated $L$-function $L(s,\pi)$ satisfies some good conditions; for example, it satisfies the functional equation of the Riemann type, and has the analytic continuation to
the whole complex plane, where it is holomorphic except possibly for a pole at $s = 1$.
I wonder if we have the lower bound at the edge of the critical strip $\Re s=1$ such that
$$ |L(1+it,\pi)|  \gg  (  N  (1+|t|)   )^{-\varepsilon} ?$$
for any $\varepsilon>0$. And I also ask if there exists a better bound compared with the above estimate?
I think a good reference should be Li's paper-Upper bounds on L-functions at the edge of the critical strip on IMRN; see https://www.et-fine.com/10.1093/imrn/rnp148. However, it appears that there is no a direct conclusion??
If any expert knows some knowledge upon this, please give some valuable comments or certain relevant references.
Thanks in advance.

If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

This is not known. The best known lower bound is due to Brumley (2013), to be found in an Appendix to a paper by Lapid, which gives that
$$|L(1+it,\pi)|  \gg_{\pi_{\infty},\varepsilon}  (  N  (1+|t|)   )^{-m-\varepsilon}.$$
Note that the implied constant depends on the archimedean parameters of $\pi$ (as necessary). Alternatively, if $N$ is replaced by the analytic conductor of $\pi$, then the implied constant will only depend on $m$ and $\varepsilon$. A small improvement in the $t$-aspect was achieved  by Qiao Zhang (2022).
On the other hand, if $\pi$ is not the determinant twist of a self-dual cuspidal irreducible representation, then the sought lower bound (with exponent $-\varepsilon$) is certainly true. I don't know if this is written anywhere, but it should follow from the work of Brumley (2019) published as an Appendix to a paper by Humphries.

Many thanks for explaining the history of this direction and the development of this topic with new references. But what's astonishing is that the lower bounds for $L(1+it, \pi)$ at $\Re s=1$ and $L(1, \pi)$ at $s=1$ are totally different! Thanks.

@user528074 1. I added the dependence of the implied constant on $\pi_\infty$ (as necessary). 2. It is not clear what you mean by "totally different". The best known lower bound for $L(1,\pi)$ is just a special case of the best known lower bound for $L(1+it,\pi)$. In fact the two problems are equivalent, because $$L(1+it,\pi)=L(1,\pi\otimes|\det|^{it}).$$ 3. f you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!
